# Firefox does not trigger hitCallback in Google Analytics while tracking outbound links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I read a lot of tutorials how to measure outbound links with Google analytics..
I have this code:

```
<a onclick="return trackOutboundLink(this);" href="google.com" target="_blank">
   link
</a>
```

And this is at the bottom of my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-6', 'my-site.tld');
ga('send', 'pageview');

trackOutboundLink = function(o) {
  ga('send', 'event', "outbound", "click", o.href, {'hitCallback': function() {
      alert("OK");  
    }
  });
 return true;
}

</script>
```

In google chrome it works like a charm - I click on the link and alert is fired + new tab is openned.

But in Mozzila Firefox it doesn't work.. I guess that google send data, but never trigger callback..

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with Firefox Adblock plugin which was blocking google analytics requests

Answer (score 2):

The following article explains how to implement this without breaking things for users who use AdBlock or similar tools:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/24/outbound-link-tracking.html

Comment: if (ga.q) { return true; } // worked for me when GA was blocked, as suggested by the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return` from the onclick, and adding `return false;` after you call your function.

```
<a onclick="trackOutboundLink(this); return false;" href="google.com" target="_blank">
   link
</a>
```

Also, remove `return true;` to your trackOutboundLink function.

Comment: It didn't help.. But I already figured this out .. for some strange reason, my AdBlock plugin in Firefox blocks Google Analytics requests.. 

But thank you for your advice Blexy :-)